# How to consume datas generated by iot devices?

Tags: java, spring

I must create a small IOT platform based on Spring Boot/Java 8.

Context: Devices send some various informations to the platform. I must save them and after consume them in an analysis algorithm.

Constraint: I want it all be async and the platform must be based on Java8/Spring technologies or must be easily integrated in a spring boot app.

What I imagine? I thought send devices' informations to Async Spring REST controller and save them async in Mongodb.
I have already the analysis algorithm based on Google Guava Event Bus.

To resume, I have datas from devices in Mongodb database and an algorithm based on Java POJO and the last part which is missing is transform datas from devices to Java POJO.

With which technologies can I do that? Spring Reactor? RxJava? Something else? And how can I put this in place?

I search something simple to put in place which can easily scale by instance duplication for example. For the moment, I thought that Spring Cloud technologies is a bit too big for my purpose.

Comment: Nothing for the moment. I search ideas. I'm looking Spring batch. It seems to do the job. I just don't know how many entries by second could be handle with this framework...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should have a look at [Spring XD](http://projects.spring.io/spring-xd/) engine.

Spring XD Enables Different Sources (HTTP, FTP, MQTT, File etc), Transformers, Filters, Sinks (HTTP, FTP, MQTT, File etc).

Please check [this](http://shazsterblog.blogspot.com/2015/04/simple-twitter-sentiment-notification.html) post on a small IoT Project based on Spring XD and Twitter API.

Comment: I saw that a good Spring XD architecture is based on at least 3 nodes. Is that true? We don't have enough money to buy 3 nodes supervised by an IT enterprise for the moment. It's why I look for a cheap solution for starting.

Comment: In Production yes. But if you want to just try out things it is a good start.